# Creating key database using private key and signed certificate

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, rsa, pki

I have a RSA private key and a signed certificate. I need to convert/import into key database (key3.db, cert8.db). Is there a way to do this using certutil tool?

I tried googling but i was not able to find a way to do this?

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance,
F